# Callable and Future return exception

Tags: java, exception, concurrency, future, callable

I have follwoing code.

```
Future<Integer> future = Executor.execute(callable);
            Integer i;
            try {
                i = future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return MESSAGE_INT_CODE;
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return i;
```

where `ExecutionException` can contain other exception say `ABCException`.
and my calling code is catching `ABCException` which is runtime exception, so if `ExecutionException` is occured how would I know it is because of `ABCException`?
`ExecutionException` due to some exception when my `public call()` method run. and call method may have some `ABCException`

should I write like this ?

```
 catch (ExecutionException e) {
                     throw new ABCException(e.getMessage());
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     //e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "where `ExecutionException` can some other exception"? Can *be* some other exception? Can *contain* some other exception? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: @jon sorry..its typo..executionException due to some exception when my public call() method run. and call method may have some ABCException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `e.getCause() instanceof ABCException`

Answer (score 1):

If exception occurs during execution of call() method, ExecutorService catches it and put it in an ExecutionException. And when you call future.get(); future throws ExecutionException which contains exception from your call method. So if I understand you correctly, you code may look like this:

```
try {
        future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if(cause instanceof ABCException) {
            // cast throwable to ABCException and rethrow it
            throw (ABCxception) cause;
        }else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
```